# laravel validation the number of forging key not greater than the id of anther table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

I am working with `laravel` 
and `laravel validation` is best validation I have ever used but now I have table with `foreign` key in anther table like this

```
  ADD CONSTRAINT `items_item_color_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`item_color`) REFERENCES `colors` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `items_item_default_unit_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`item_default_unit`) REFERENCES `units` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `items_item_inserter_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`item_inserter`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `items_item_state_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`item_state`) REFERENCES `item_states` (`id`);
```

now in the request validation i wrote this

```
'item_id' => 'required|unique:items|max:250|min:1',
'item_desc_ar' => 'required|unique:items|max:250|min:1',
'item_desc_en' => 'max:250|min:1|nullable',
'item_default_unit' => 'required|integer',
```

Now in `item_defult_unit` its required and integer but in post its could be more than the id in the item_units 
how can i let the validation like this

```
'item_default_unit' => 'required|integer|and not more than id in anther table',
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can simply append  `max` validation in  your case, you need to add something like `max:$valueFromOtherTable` , where you can write eloquent query to get the `$valueFromOtherTable`

Comment: could you wright full example

Comment: yes writing answer, what is name of the other table?

Comment: table name is units

Comment: If solution works just mark answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `max` validation with dynamic value as below:

```
'item_default_unit' => 'required|integer|max:'.Unit::max('id')
//model name is Unit
```

Its simple trick to have dynamic value for `max` by fetching it from model.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
$unit = DB::table('units')->latest()->first();
'item_default_unit' => 'required|integer|max:'.$unit->id
```